# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying build maven project in Jenkins for executing selenium scripts, I got java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE the following like
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238) at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136) at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71) at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120) at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48) at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332) at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:653) at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:171) at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven31Launcher.java:153) at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:130) ... 21 more channel stopped ERROR: Failed to parse POMs hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:180) at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71) at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120) at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48) at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332) at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) at ......remote call to Channel to Maven [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java, -cp, C:\Users\User.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;F:\sambaselenium\jarfiles\apache-maven-3.5.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;F:\sambaselenium\jarfiles\apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main, F:\sambaselenium\jarfiles\apache-maven-3.5.0, C:\Users\User.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.56.jar, C:\Users\User.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar, C:\Users\User.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar, 53935](Native Method) at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416) at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220) at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781) at hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:161) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:840) at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534) at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738) at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529) at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98) at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136) at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71) at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120) at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48) at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332) at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:184) ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238) at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181) ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:653) at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:171) at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven31Launcher.java:153) at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:130) ... 21 more Finished: FAILURE

my Jenkins version is 1.658
maven is 3.5.0 and jdk 1.8
I configure everything good, I am unable to build

Comment: Can you show your pom file

Comment: The error says it all `InvocationTargetException and DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE`. The file `DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE` is not invoked properly. Thanks

Comment: Thank You DebanjanB. I find solution I am using Jenkins 1.658 maven 3.5.0 and JDK 1.8, I just changed maven version 3.3.9 then  it (problem) is solved